# Why does `aio_write` disallow concurrent buffer access?

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

The [Linux man-page for `aio_write`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_write) says

> The buffer area being written out must not be *accessed* during the operation or undefined results may occur.

My emphasis on "accessed", which strictly interpreted is not only stores to the buffer, but also loads from the buffer.

The man-page on Mac OS X says

> Modifications of the Asynchronous I/O Control Block structure or the buffer contents after the request has been enqueued, but before the request has completed, are not allowed.

This sounds slightly more reasonable; the buffer can be read from, but not modified. The consequences of a violation are still left vague, though.

Thinking about how this might be implemented in the OS, I can't why a read access would ever be a problem, and the only problem I can imagine from a concurrent write would be that the actual data written could be some arbitrary mix of the initial buffer contents and the concurrent stores to the buffer.

Undefined behaviour opens up a lot of possibilities, however, and with that in mind we could get SIGSEGV on access (the underlying page was locked to prevent concurrent access?), or reads could return garbage data (the file system does in-place encryption or compression?), or the file could be left with permanently unreadable blocks (block checksummed, then modified concurrently, then written out?). Undefined behaviour does not even exclude crashing the storage device firmware, or the OS.

My question is, what could actually, reasonably happen, given the systems and hardware we have? I assume the language is left intentionally vague to not constrain future implementations.

Comment: Who knows?  Does it matter at all?  I don't know why anyone would want to access the structs/buffers/s before I/O completion is notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux, BSD (MacOS is a BSD flavour), POSIX say different things.

POSIX says:

> For any system action that changes the process memory space while an
>   asynchronous I/O is outstanding to the address range being changed,
>   the result of that action is undefined.

Linux manual seems more restrictive, two possibilites:

1. It's matter of interpretation. Author may thought about **write accesses** but simply wrote **accesses**,
2. It may be **any access** because implementation is free to use any mechanism that may forbid any access (severe locking or protection during IO).

BSD also says:

> If    the request is successfully enqueued, the value of iocb-_aio_offset
>        can be modified during the   request as context, so this value must not be
>        referenced   after the request is enqueued

thus explicitly forbids some **read accesses** (to the control structure).

As Martin said in comment: *I don't know why anyone would want to access the structs/buffers/s before I/O completion is notified*. But it is also too restrictive: ok, that is clear for **write access**, but one can imagine (while not common) a scenario where you want **read access** to the buffer during the IO (writing a framebuffer content while displaying it - or alike).

Whatever, if you violate the restrictions anything bad may happen, so don't violate them.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, what could actually, reasonably happen, given the systems and hardware we have? I assume the language is left intentionally vague to not constrain future implementations.

Take a close look at the API:

```
int aio_write(struct aiocb *aiocbp);
```

Notice it does not take pointer to const? The warning is quite clear, once you pass the aiocbp parameter to aio_write(), the data belongs to the AIO code until the operation is complete. You could read the data, but what can you reasonably expect its state to be? According the API and the spec, you can't expect anything at all. Even observed behavior could appear to be totally random. In addition, AIO may lock the cache lines for that block for performance (consistency) reasons, any reads from another core could interfere with the performance of the entire system.

In the absence of lock/unlock semantics, anytime you pass non-const data off to another thread of execution, you cannot reasonably expect to consistently read anything from that data block, until whatever API you are using has signaled completion of whatever work you expect it to perform. This is true whether their documentation says so or not.